# Yiiframework First time login

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I'm currently busy with a project that needs users to go to a specific page to create a profile when they log in for the first time (and haven't created one yet). Honestly, I don't know where to start. I would like to do it in a good way.

So in short:

```
User signs up -> logs in -> needs to fill in form before anything else is allowed -> continue to rest of application
```

Question: What is a neat way to do this? A solution that isn't going to give me problems in the future development of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [filters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter). In every controller where the completed profile is neeeded add this code:

```
    public function filters() {
        return array(
            'completedProfile + method1, method2, method3', // Replace your actions here
        );
    }
```

In your base controller (if you don't use base controller, in any controllers) you need to create the filter named completedProfile with the simular code:

```
    public function filterCompletedProfile($filterChain) {
        $criteria = new CDBCriteria(array(
            'condition' => 'id = :id AND firstname IS NOT NULL AND lastname IS NOT NULL',
            'params' => array(':id' => Yii::app()->user->getId())
        ));
        $count = User::model()->count($criteria);

        if ($count == 1) {
            $filterChain->run();
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('user/profile'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly add a field to the user profile database table which denotes if they have filled out their profile information. Something like `profile_complete`. Then you can do a test on pages to see if `profile_complete` is true and display the page if so, and display the profile page if not.